# ES6 Promise blocks page

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Given the following test code:

```
var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    for(var i=0;i<10000000;++i)
        for(var y=i;y<10000000;++y)
            z = i + y;
    resolve();
});
p.then(function(){alert("resolved");});
```

This code should run asynchronously, but it blocks all interaction with the page. Why?

This was tested in Chrome 44, according to [this table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) Promises should be fully implemented.

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/cgs1xmht/) (warning: blocks the tab)

Comment: Such a tough loop always blocks the page, regardless where/when it runs. Promises do not provide concurrency/parallelism!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> This code should run asynchronously

Yes and no, it depends on what part of that code you're talking about. The code in your promise executor (the function you pass into `new Promise`) is **not** run asynchronously. From [§25.4.3.1](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-promise-executor), step 10:

> Let completion be Call(executor, undefined, «resolvingFunctions.[[Resolve]], resolvingFunctions.[[Reject]]»).

Note that there's nothing there about `new Promise` calling the executor asynchronously. (It's a "[Call](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-call)" rather than "[EnqueueJob](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-enqueuejob)".)

The asynchronous guarantee applies to `then`, not `new Promise`. ([§25.4.5.3](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-promise.prototype.then) and [§25.4.5.3.1](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-performpromisethen).) The guarantee is that even if the promise is already resolved, your callback will *not* be called synchronously with the `then` call, it will be after because it will be scheduled via "[EnqueueJob](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-enqueuejob)".

So what happens in your code is:

1. You call `new Promise`, which calls your executor *synchronously*.
2. Eventually the executor returns and `new Promise` completes, giving us `p`.
3. You call `p.then(...)`; the call queues a job to call your callback and returns immediately.
4. The current job in the JavaScript job queue runs to completion.
5. The job that calls to your callback is executed, calling the callback.

Comment: Is this some _new_ definition of async of which I was previously unaware? How can it be async but still run on the same thread that started it? Or am I missing something basic (which could turn out to be embarrasing for me)? :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: The same way ajax is async: A new task is scheduled, the current task's close runs to completion, and then the new task is run.

Comment: I should have said: *"...and then the new task is run **on the same thread**."* :-) (And I should probably have used the JS term "job" rather than the HTML5 term "task", but it comes to the same thing...)

Comment: That makes more sense now, the promise itself is not async/deferred, just the call to the resolve/reject function later on.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Yup. I think the assumption is that code in the promise executor function is going to start some other async process. The async guarantee on `then` is to avoid chaos -- code calling `then` should *know* whether the callback will happen right then or later. With promises that don't guarantee async `then` callbacks (I'm looking at you, jQuery), code calling `then` can't know what's going to happen without inspecting the state of the promise before calling `then`, which is just dumb. :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: It sounds like you are confusing "async" with "parallel/concurrent". That long-running loop is always running synchronously and blocking your page. To avoid clogging, you will have to break up the loop in chunks.

Comment: To clarify pax's comment: *"That makes more sense now, the promise itself is not async/deferred, just the call to the resolve/reject function later on."* It's not the call to *resolve/reject* that's async. It's the call to the `then` callback. While it's *usually* the case that you do something async in the `Promise` constructor and then call `resolve/reject` later, it's not required. It *is* required that an conforming implementation calls the `then` asynchronously (not during the `then` call itself).

Answer (score 2):

### Asynchronously != In parallel

JavaScript is event-based and single-threaded. Promises don't let you escape that. Only built-in browser functions have the power to do things  actually *in parallel*.

Therefore, in JavaScript, when we say `f` in `p.then(f)` is called *asynchronously*, it just means *later* in the same thread, i.e. in a subsequent run-to-completion task separate from the one we're in now. This is a good thing, and is why you don't need to lock things with mutexes (no data races from concurrent access).

This confusion about JS seems common, to the point where specifications are [changing their language](https://github.com/w3ctag/promises-guide/issues/31) to make this distinction clearer.

All that said, the part about only browser functions running things in parallel isn't entirely true anymore. To truly run intensive computations in parallel in JavaScript, look at  [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers), a new well-isolated concept of launching threads that might as well be running in a different tab from you, except you can talk to them through messages. Since they share no data space with you, they don't upset the JavaScript threading guarantee (or change anything I'm saying here).

### Promises

The point of promises is not to offer concurrent access, but to address the backwardness of callbacks and make code easier to reason about, and perhaps more importantly, solve error propagation through chains of asynchronous operations (regardless of whether they run in parallel or not).

Promises also make it trivial to launch and wait for more than one asynchronous operation at a time (with `Promise.all` and `Promise.race`), something that is insanely complicated to get right (without bugs) and reason about with just callbacks.

Comment: *"JavaScript is event-based and single-threaded..."* **on browsers**. :-) (And in NodeJS)

Comment: When is it not event-based and single-threaded? There are no lock constructs in JS, and the language is run-to-completion.

Comment: Any time the host environment makes it not so. In particular, JavaScript on the JVM (Rhino, Nashorn) is multi-threaded. JavaScript, *the language*, is essentially silent about threading. The host environment can be multi-threaded, or not. I say "essentially silent" because run-to-completion relates in a way to *a* thread (but doesn't require it to be the only one).